# ¿Porque da error en los lifecycle methods de react si no los estoy usando?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto con `react.js` para aprender `redux`. Es basicamente un Login y una pagina principal. Y utilizo `redux` para saber si el usuario tiene o no una sesión iniciada.

Cuando el usuario ha ingresado sus credenciales, y presiona el botón de inicio de sesión, se hace una petición a un *API*. Si el *API* responde true, con `redux`, cambio de `authUser` de false a true y por medio de `history.push()` lo redirecciono a el componente en la ruta `/dashboard`.

Este es el código del componente principal:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Redirect, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import Login from "../../views/Login/Login.js";
import Layout from "../Layout/Layout";

const RestrictedRoute = ({component: Component, authUser, ...rest}) => {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        authUser
          ? <Component {...props} />
          : <Redirect
            to={‌{
              pathname: '/login',
              state: {from: props.location}
            }}
        />}
    />
  );
}

class Main extends Component {
  render () {
    const { authUser, match, history } = this.props;
    if (authUser) {
      history.push("/");
    }
    return (
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/login' component={Login}/>
        <RestrictedRoute path={`${match.url}`} authUser={authUser}                         component={Layout}/>
      </Switch>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    authUser: state.authUser,
  };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Main);
```

Después de que se presiona el botón de inicio de sesión, y si los credenciales son correctos debería redireccionar a la ruta `/`, Que tiene `Layout` como componente a renderizar.

Y este es el componente `Layout`:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

import "perfect-scrollbar/css/perfect-scrollbar.css";

import withStyles from "@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles";

import Footer from "../../components/UI/Footer/Footer";

import dashboardStyle from "../../assets/jss/material-dashboard-react/layouts/dashboardStyle";

class Layout extends Component {

  render() {
    const { classes, match } = this.props;
    console.log(match);
    return (
      <div className={classes.wrapper}>
        <div className={classes.mainPanel} ref="mainPanel">
          <div className={classes.content}>
            <div className={classes.container}>
              Layout
            </div>
          </div>
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Layout.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default withStyles(dashboardStyle)(Layout);
```

Pero me da este error:

> "Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component
>   repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or
>   componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to
>   prevent infinite loops."

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya llevo algunas horas buscando una solución... pero no he encontrado nada. ¿Tienes alguna idea de lo que pueda estar pasando?
¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: El error básicamente es que estás llamando a una función que modifica el estado dentro del render. Si te das cuenta tu función `history.push("/");` se va a llamar cada que se haga un render, y cada cambio en la historia hace un render, por lo que entra en un bucle infinito causando así el error que tienes. Para manejar este comportamiento lo mejor es que uses algunos métodos del lifecycle de react para que cuando recibas nuevas props puedas actualizar ese valor sin necesidad de hacerlo por cada render

Comment: Gracias @GermanAlzate !! Ese era el problema, no me había dado cuenta. He implementado "componentDidUpdate" para hacer la comprobación y ya todo funciona correctamente.